# Unable to use Javascript functionality in tailwind css with vite in reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, vite

I am working on a react project using vite and for css I am using tailwind css. From the component section of tailwind css website I have copied template, and I am unable to get responsive functionality and show/hide menu on click

below is my header code

```
<nav class="bg-gray-800">
        <div class="mx-auto max-w-7xl px-2 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
          <div class="relative flex h-16 items-center justify-between">
            <div class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center sm:hidden">

              <button type="button" class="inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-md p-2 text-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-white" aria-controls="mobile-menu" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
            
                <svg class="block h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                  <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M3.75 6.75h16.5M3.75 12h16.5m-16.5 5.25h16.5" />
                </svg>
           
                <svg class="hidden h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                  <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
                </svg>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="flex flex-1 items-center justify-center sm:items-stretch sm:justify-start">
              <div class="flex flex-shrink-0 items-center">
                <img class="block h-8 w-auto lg:hidden" src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/mark.svg?color=indigo&shade=500" alt="Your Company" />
                  <img class="hidden h-8 w-auto lg:block" src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/mark.svg?color=indigo&shade=500" alt="Your Company"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="hidden sm:ml-6 sm:block">
                    <div class="flex space-x-4">
       
                      <a href="#" class="bg-gray-900 text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium" aria-current="page">Dashboard</a>

                      <a href="#" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium">Team</a>

                      <a href="#" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium">Projects</a>

                      <a href="#" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium">Calendar</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2 sm:static sm:inset-auto sm:ml-6 sm:pr-0">
                <button type="button" class="rounded-full bg-gray-800 p-1 text-gray-400 hover:text-white focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-white focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800">
                  <span class="sr-only">View notifications</span>
   
                  <svg class="h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M14.857 17.082a23.848 23.848 0 005.454-1.31A8.967 8.967 0 0118 9.75v-.7V9A6 6 0 006 9v.75a8.967 8.967 0 01-2.312 6.022c1.733.64 3.56 1.085 5.455 1.31m5.714 0a24.255 24.255 0 01-5.714 0m5.714 0a3 3 0 11-5.714 0" />
                  </svg>
                </button>

                <div class="relative ml-3">
                  <div>
                    <button type="button" class="flex rounded-full bg-gray-800 text-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-white focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800" id="user-menu-button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">
                      <span class="sr-only">Open user menu</span>
                      <img class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472099645785-5658abf4ff4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80" alt=""/>
                    </button> 
                  </div>


                  <div class="absolute right-0 z-10 mt-2 w-48 origin-top-right rounded-md bg-white py-1 shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none" role="menu" aria-orientation="vertical" aria-labelledby="user-menu-button" tabindex="-1">
 
                    <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" id="user-menu-item-0">Your Profile</a>
                    <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" id="user-menu-item-1">Settings</a>
                    <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" id="user-menu-item-2">Sign out</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="sm:hidden" id="mobile-menu">
            <div class="space-y-1 px-2 pt-2 pb-3">
         
              <a href="#" class="bg-gray-900 text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium" aria-current="page">Dashboard</a>

              <a href="#" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium">Team</a>

              <a href="#" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium">Projects</a>

              <a href="#" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium">Calendar</a>
            </div>
          </div>
      </nav>
```

everything is working fine but by running the above code I am getting only ui and not getting click function on menu bars or other

see the image below

[[image: see the image , I am only getting what is shown in image1]

Comment: Tailwind is CSS only - you have to implement Javascript on your own

Answer (score 0):

```
let menuMovilButton = document.getElementById('menu-movil-button');
let userMenuButton = document.getElementById('user-menu-button');
let userMenu = document.getElementById('user-menu');
let menuMovil = document.getElementById('menu-movil');

menuMovilButton.addEventListener('click', () =>{
menuMovil.classList.toggle('hidden');
});

userMenuButton.addEventListener('click', () =>{
   userMenu.classList.toggle('hidden');
});`
```

Comment: you can add this code but first you must add the id's to your corresponding tags